# Windows Key Shortcut does not work the same with Taskbar Auto-Hide

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar

This may be oddly specific but here goes...

When I have the Windows taskbar anchored to the view and I press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> (or whatever number),  it brings an application to the front view. I have Chrome pinned at the 1 slot and when I have multiple windows open for Chrome, pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> automatically selects the first Chrome window that I had previously opened (Or the first window visible when you would hover your mouse over the taskbar icon).

The problem is, and this is super picky, I'm sorry, this does not work exactly the same way when the taskbar is set to auto-hide.

When the taskbar is set to auto-hide and I hit <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> with multiple Chrome windows open, it does not automatically select the first window. Instead, it shows the thumbnails as if you were hovering on the icon. I can achieve the same original effect by just hitting <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but that's just one more key and I don't know why it should be different.

If you know a way to automatically bring up that first window even when the taskbar is set to auto-hide, I would love to know. Thanks.

I am using Windows 8.1 Pro